# VLC automatically opens when I plug in headphones

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player, chroot

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. VLC media player version 2.2.2 Weathermax. Every time I plug in my headphones, VLC media player opens. I'm wondering if I can disable this from happening.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/642404/196535). It should be possible that in `/etc/acpi/events/` something says `event=jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug` and
`action=vlc` (maybe with the full-path). Give it a look and come back to give feedback. PS> Ubuntu 16.04 is at end of life. You may want to upgrade at least to 18.04 LTS. In that case that behavior can disappear by itself.

Comment: @Hastur, I do not have an `acpi` folder under `/etc`. Full disclosure, I am running Ubuntu inside a Chromebook chroot (https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton).

Comment: It was just the idea... Check who takes care of the event management under crouton/Ubuntu.  BTW try `acpi_listen`. If it works it may be installed somewhere-else. It may be even something inside the desktop environment (if there is one). Good Luck.

Comment: PS> The info if plugged or not, e.g., can be found in `/proc/asound/card0/codec#0`. So every script looking in that file can start the action... Give it a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58109/66388) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/133809/196535) and related... IMHO I do not believe it is an _handmade_ script, for efficiency reasons. I put my penny on the system wide event handler used. [PS #2> before I meant if you try the command `acpi_listen` and it works... well, it has to be installed somewhere...]

Comment: @Hasture, thanks for your reply. So `acpi_listen` is not installed and my `/proc/asound/card0/` directory contains only folders `pcm0p`, `pcm1c`, `pcm2c`, `pcm3c`, `pcm4p`, `pcm5p`, and `pcm6p`. all of which does not have `codec#0` -- only files like `sub0/{hw_params,prealloc,status,info,prealloc_max,sw_params}`.